# get lowercase data in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have data like below in one of the column in table.

```
john;144;ny;
Nelson;154;NY;
john;144;NC;
john;144;kw;
```

I want to retrieve the rows which has lowercase in 3rd part of the data
so i need to get

```
john;144;kw;
john;144;ny;
```

is possible to get the data like this?

Comment: I have to agree with [Marc's comment below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26592015/get-lowercase-data-in-sql-server#comment41799236_26592147) - why are you storing data this way? These are clearly separate pieces of information, so please fix the design and store them in separate columns.

Comment: But it was records , already i have 20k records

Comment: Assuming that your column is called `data` then the following will extract everything after the 2nd semi-colon: `SUBSTRING(Data, 1 + CHARINDEX(';', Data, CHARINDEX(';', Data) + 1), LEN(Data))` - I have to agree with Aaron and Marc though, this would be better stored in three columns, if you frequently need the data as a concatenated string add a computed column that concatenates your three columns together. The one time hit of separating the data will be more than worth it in the long term.

Comment: @Abhiram are you saying 20,000 rows is beyond the point of no return? You can fix this. Easily. Better now than when you have 20 million.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not really answer your question, it certainly adds nothing to Marc's existing answer in terms of resolving your actual problem, it is merely meant as a demonstration of how simple it is to correct your design (this whole script runs in about a second on my local express instance of SQL Server 2012).

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T
(
    ThreePartData VARCHAR(60)
);

-- INSERT 20,000 ROWS
INSERT dbo.T (ThreePartData)
SELECT  t.ThreePartName
FROM    (VALUES ('john;144;ny;'), ('Nelson;154;NY;'), ('john;144;NC;'), ('john;144;kw;')) t (ThreePartName)
        CROSS JOIN 
        (   SELECT  TOP (5000) Number = 1
            FROM    sys.all_objects a
                    CROSS APPLY sys.all_objects b
        ) n;
GO

-- HERE IS WHERE THE CHANGES START
/**********************************************************************/
-- ADD A COLUMN FOR EACH COMPONENT
ALTER TABLE dbo.T ADD PartOne VARCHAR(20),
                    PartTwo VARCHAR(20),
                    PartThree VARCHAR(20);
GO
-- UPDATE THE PARTS WITH THEIR CORRESPONDING COMPONENT
UPDATE  dbo.T
SET     PartOne = PARSENAME(REPLACE(ThreePartData, ';', '.') + 't', 4),
        PartTwo = PARSENAME(REPLACE(ThreePartData, ';', '.') + 't', 3),
        PartThree = PARSENAME(REPLACE(ThreePartData, ';', '.') + 't', 2);
GO

-- GET RID OF CURRENT COLUMN
ALTER TABLE dbo.T DROP COLUMN ThreePartData;
GO

-- CREATE A NEW COMPUTED COLUMN THAT REBUILDS THE CONCATENATED STRING
ALTER TABLE dbo.T ADD ThreePartData AS CONCAT(PartOne, ';', PartTwo, ';', PartThree, ';');
GO

-- OR FOR VERSIONS BEFORE 2012
--ALTER TABLE dbo.T ADD ThreePartData AS PartOne + ';' + PartTwo + ';' + PartThree + ';';
```

Then your query is as simple as:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    T
WHERE LOWER(PartThree) = PartThree  COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;
```

And since you have recreated a computed column with the same name, any select statements in use will not be affected, although updates and inserts will need addressing.

Answer (score 5):

Force a case-sensitive matching, and then compare forced-lowercase to original:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ..
WHERE LOWER(name) = name  COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
                                                 ^^---case sensitive
```

If the name is all-lower to start with, then LOWER() won't change it, and you'll get a match. If it's something like `John`, then you'd be doing `john = John` and the case-sensitivity will fail the match.

Comment: Thanks how to compare lowercase for 3rd part of string ?

Comment: use string operations to extract that part, then use the lower/case-sensitive stuff. and you really should normalize your design, since you're obviously now suffering from not having done so. never store multiple independent bits of data in a single field, ESPECIALLY when you need to access those bits separately.

Comment: @Abhiram Are there any constraints that ensure that the data will always be in the form `s1;s2;s3;`? Never `s1;s2;s3;s4;` or `s1;s2;` or missing semi-colons altogether?

Comment: Yes it has constraints data will be in same form

Comment: `WHERE LOWER(PARSENAME(REPLACE(col,';','.')+'x',2)) 
= PARSENAME(REPLACE(col,';','.')+'x',2) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;`. [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59874/2). See how ugly that is? Can you imagine how much prettier it would be if you didn't have to break up the string before comparing?

Answer (score 0):

Using `BINARY_CHECKSUM` we can retrieve the rows which has lowercase or upper case

```
CREATE TABLE #test
  (
     NAME VARCHAR(50)
  )

INSERT INTO #test
VALUES      ('john;144;ny;'),
            ('Nelson;154;NY;'),
            ('john;144;NC;'),
            ('john;144;kw;')

SELECT *
FROM   #test
WHERE  Binary_checksum(NAME) = Binary_checksum(Lower(NAME))
```

OUTPUT

```
name
-----------
john;144;ny;
john;144;kw;
```